# After Noobs Raspbian installation Pi won't start

Tags: raspbian, noobs, pi-4

Brand new raspberry pi 4, brand new SD card.

I downloaded and transferred Noobs onto the SD card, booted it, set up Raspbian with no issues, but then it told me to reboot to apply changes.

Since that, it won't boot. I have no HDMI output, the green LED is not blinking and my keyboard and mouse (both backlit) display varying levels of intensity.

I would normally format the SD card but my main machine (Linux mint 19) sees the SD card as 3 separate disks (`root`, `boot`, `SETTINGS`)

I do have another available SD card but would prefer to use this same one - otherwise this hobby is getting a bit expensive.

Edit: I have looked at raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151
but as my power supply is official and brand new, and everything is plugged in correctly. I also uncommented the line in the `confid.txt` file to force the HDMI to safe mode.

Comment: Work your way through https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151

Comment: @joan see my edit

Comment: Scrap your SDCard and write plain Raspbian Buster [1] (NOT NOOBS) to it with BalenaEtcher [2]. [1] https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_latest  [2] https://www.balena.io/etcher/

Comment: @Dougie How can I format this SD card now that my computer ses it as 3 separate drives?

Comment: Nobody is asking you to format the card.  Just overwrite it with Raspbian using etcher or similar.  That will get rid of any existing file systems on the card.

Comment: @joan the card shows up as three separate disks, which one should I overwrite?

Comment: You need to overwrite the device not a file system within the device.  I assumed etcher did this automatically.  The device will typically have a name like `/dev/sdd` whereas the individual file systems would be `/dev/sdd1`, `/dev/sdd2`, `/dev/sdd3` etc.  Note that `/dev/sdd` is an example.  I don't know what is attached to your machine.

Comment: What OS are you using to try to create your bootable card? If it's Windows or MacOS just run Etcher and follow the simple instructions. If it's Linux you need to unzip the Raspbian image and dd it to /dev/sdd (or whereever your SDCard appears).

Comment: @joan the device is listed as 3 separate disks in my file manager, but I admit I didn't `df` the situation o I'll check that later.
@Dougie I'm using Linux Mint 19 - can UNetBootIn be used to set up the SD card?

Answer (score 4):

You want to use Raspbian, not NOOBS. As you see NOOBS is very error prone so most of us use the Raspbian image direct. You can get it from [Raspbian Download](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/). Please don't follow the link for NOOBS given on that side. Instead use the other given link [installation guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md).

Don't worry about the shown partitions from the SD Card (I suppose you mean that) that you named "*3 separate disks in my file manager*" in a comment. Just flash the image as described. It will automatically reformat the SD Card. But have attention to select the SD Card and not any drive from your computer!